# Is it correct to say “not needed to be “?

Tags: grammar

Whenever someone says sorry, we simply say It’s fine, no problem etc. 
Instead of that  i want to use ‘Not needed to be’ because i want to say ‘No please don’t say sorry, don’t feel that you are guilty’

Can somebody help me to clearify whether it is correct or not to use that line ?

Answer (score 2):

It's nearly grammatical, but we only leave out the subject (in colloquial use) if it's obvious what the subject is. In any case, it's not something a native speaker would say.

I suspect that what you want is

> There's no need.

This isn't something you'd normally say in response to "Sorry", but it is something you might say if somebody tries to make reparation for something they've done, and you don't want that.

Another possibility is

> You don't need to be.

but again, that's not usual.